# Windows 10, connect to a projector by IP address

Tags: windows-10, screen-sharing

I have a Windows 10 machine and a projector. Both of them are connected to the same network (*well, not exactly - addresses are: 10.5.**50**.45 and 10.5.**51**.20*). And I need to share my screen on this projector.

Usually `WIN + P` does the job, but in this case auto-discovery cannot find the projector (*most probably because of not exactly the same subnet*).

However, in Windows 7 (and Windows 8, apparently) there is an option to specify an IP-address to connect to, when auto-discovery fails. I've just tested it, because I have a Windows 7 machine too, and everything works fine, I can share my screen from Windows 7 on this projector if I specify its IP-address manually:

[image: manual connection to projector]

[image: setting the IP address of projector]

But in Windows 10 there is no such option. I cannot find it anywhere - how can I specify the IP-adress of projector? Is there at least some PowerShell command in case it's not possible via standard settings GUI-dialogs?

Comment: What is the subnet mask? because 10.5.50.45 and 10.5.51.20 are on the same subnet for a /23 or larger network.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot where you can specify the IP in Windows 7?

Comment: @Scorpion99, added screenshots to the post.

Comment: @Hennes, I changed IP-addresses from real values in this post (just in case), however third octet is different. Anyway, they question is about how to connect to projector via IP-address in Windows 10.

Comment: Is there any software which came with your projector?It might have this option inside.

Comment: @Scorpion99, on Windows 7 (and Windows 8, apparently) it works out-of-the-box with projectors from different vendors, without installing any additional software. I'm looking for the same functionality on Windows 10.

Comment: Recent versions of Windows use _Miracast_ or _Miracast over Infrastructure_ for this functionality. Windows 7 uses an entirely different technology for network projects. IIRC it relies on Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) and Windows CE running on the projector. You will not be able to make both work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a chat with the [official Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/) and after 1 hour, 2 different support specialists and updating to Windows 10 1703, I finally got the answer about connecting to a projector via network on Windows 10:

> ...the only way for now in Windows 10 1703 is auto-detection

Although, there is a chance that this particular support specialist doesn't know everything about that, I tend to believe that it is so - you cannot specify the IP address of a projector manually. You can only rely on auto-detection.

Anyway, I've created a corresponding feature-request in their Feedback Hub (can't give you the link, because there is no share option there). Will see, if it will be noticed.